# Kolmogorov width for cartesian products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For an operator $T:X\to Y$  between Banach spaces with unit balls $B_X$ and $B_Y$ the sequence of *Kolmogorov widths* is
$$
\delta_n(T)=\inf\lbrace \delta>0: T(B_X)\subseteq \delta B_Y +L \text{ for a subspace $L$ of $Y$ with dim$(L)\le n$}\rbrace.
$$
It is well-known that $T$ is compact if and only if $\delta_n(T)\to 0$.

We endow the cartesian product with the norm $\|(x_1,x_2)\|_{X\times X}= \max\lbrace \|x_1\|_X,\|x_2\|_X\rbrace$
and consider $T\times T: X\times X\to Y\times Y$, $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto(T(x_1),T(x_2))$. A rather trivial estimate is then
$$
\delta_{2n}(T\times T) \le \delta_n(T)
$$
(because $T(B_X)\subseteq \delta B_Y+L$ implies $T(B_X)\times T(B_X)\subseteq \delta(B_Y\times B_Y)+L\times L$).

The question: Is there a universal constant $c$ such that $\delta_{2n}(T\times T) \ge c \delta_n(T)$?

For Hilbert spaces this is true because $(\delta_n(T))_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is just the sequence of singular numbers, i.e. the decreasing sequence of square roots of the eigenvalues of $T^*T$, and it is easy to calculate the singular numbers for $T\times T$ at least for $X\times X$ endowed with the norm $\sqrt{\|x_1\|_X^2+\|x_2\|_X^2}$. The constant $c$ then only comes from comparison of this norm with the maximum norm.

Comment: Thanks, quid (because I don't know the answer--sorry about that, Jochen).  :)

Comment: It looks like to answer this question one has to investigate more than it is done: what are the possible causes for $\delta_n(T)\ge\alpha$? If it happens because $T(B_X)$ contains a ball of radius $\ge\alpha$ of an $(n+1)$-dimensional subspace of $Y$, the answer is "Yes" by Krein-Krasnoselskii-Milman argument. But this is not the only reason, there is another well-known reason, the simplest case of which you can find on page 5 of this [paper](http://facpub.stjohns.edu/ostrovsm/OstrovskiiBAuMS2010preprint.pdf). In this case the answer is also "Yes". The general case requires more understaning.